# Changing anisotropy after render do not work

Tags: three.js

I have problem with updating `THREE` above version 137 - If I change `anisotropy` after an object was rendered, it breaks the material on the object.

For example, let's use from three.js examples `webgl_loader_texture_tga.html`. Now let's add into `init()`:

```
scene.background = new THREE.Color()
window.setTimeout( () => {

    mesh2.material.map.anisotropy = 16;
    mesh2.material.map.needsUpdate = true;

}, 1000 );
```

After timeout runs, object changes into black and we get these warnings to the console:

```
[.WebGL-00005420002AC600] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Level of detail outside of range.
[.WebGL-00005420002AC600] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Texture format does not support mipmap generation.
```

[image: changing anisotropy after object object is rendered breaks material of the object]

**EDIT:**

Live example can be found here: https://codepen.io/kajbo/pen/mdpwybO

Please notice that if you change `THREE` version to 137 or below everything works as expected.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the issue with a full live example?

Comment: @Mugen87 I have added codepen. It seems to me that THREE removed support of changing anisotropy from version 138, but I hope I am just missing something.

Comment: Thanks for the codepen. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bug in `three.js`. I have filed a PR at GitHub to solve this issue: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/23808